# propertycollection - mango wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

Hi my problem is this:

I have a class with many properties, so I decide to store all in a property collection.
These properties are needed for configuration purpose so I want to make a page with all or part of these properties.

I'd like to bind in xaml page but I can't figure out how use command and INotifyPropertyChanged for update xaml, I mean that I'd like to bind this properties in xaml way

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource <property collection name>}, Path=<name of property>}"/>
```

any solution?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a converter that takes the propertyCollection as a parameter and you could then create text output of whatever type/format you want from that.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think this might be achievable is with a custom markup extension.  Unfortunately these are only just coming to Silverlight in v5. There is no telling if/when it will come to WP7.